# Verify the data from the last element of xpath with dynamic list c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

[image: DataList]

From the above image the new data that I add gets added to the last page but there can be similar name and I need to verify the data using the ID as shown. So I am trying to figure out the way to store text values from the id and when the new data is added it should verify the last newly added ID. Any ideas?

```
        int i = 1;
        bool found = false;
        string ID;
        try
        {

            IWebElement LastPage = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]"));
            LastPage.Click();
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) ;
            {
                ID= Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]")).Text;
                if (??)
            }
```

Comment: I don't see your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @viet-pham said, using last is a good idea, you can also use a relative xpath like:

```
//table/tbody/tr[last()-1]/td
```

and you don't need to use `[1]` since you are using `FindElement` and not `FindElements` and is returning the first element found.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use for loop to get the last item, just put last() to select the final **tr element**

**In your case**:

```
IWebElement lastElement = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr)[last()]/td[1]"));
ID = lastElement.Text;
```

**In additional:** because the last row is the total, so you must change to the row before it => [last()-1]

Comment: It is really, really a bad practice to use XPaths that start at the root (HTML) tag. Don't do this.

Comment: Sorry, I think you get wrong idea, I just recopy the XPath from @Harsh thakkar.

Comment: @JeffC, the thing I point here is last() function, not absolute or relative XPath.